# Diagnostic Tools Visual Studio 2015 - For Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, debug-diagnostic-tool

I try to run Diagnostic tools when I run my project for my smarthphone (In desktop-local machine works perfectly) but when I do it, erros message is showed:

```
"The Diagnostic Tools window does not support the current debugging configuration"
```

In Microsoft page have a small information about that: 
The Diagnostic Tools window currently does not support (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/16/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx):

```
"Windows Store projects that are using JavaScript
 Windows Store projects that are running on a Windows Phone
 Debugging when Managed or Native Compatibility Mode is checked in Tools –> Options –> Debugging"
```

I put the configuration : **Debug --> ARM**

I try to do this: [Visual Studio 2015 diagnostics tool does not support current debugging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167640/visual-studio-2015-diagnostics-tool-does-not-support-current-debugging-configura) but now work.

Someone know other tool to analyse my app in mobile phone, or what resolve my this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Not work.
I try all solutions and not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, the Diagnostic Tools window currently does not support:

> Windows Store projects that are running on a Windows Phone

If you want to analyse your app in mobile phone, you can use analysis tools in the Performance and Diagnostic hub. For more information, please see [Run analysis tools from the Performance and Diagnostic page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435909.aspx).

Comment: but this informations are right when use Emulatores not real devices.

Thanks