# VS2015: Diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly and no "Diagnostic Hub" in output window

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

when starting up an application i always get an error in the "Diagnostic Tools" Window saying:

> The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly. The Diagnostics Hub output in the Output window may contain additional information.

I already found a solution for [VS2015 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/06/known-issue-for-diagnostics-tool-window-in-visual-studio-2015-rc-the-diagnostic-tools-failed-unexpectedly.aspx) but this didn't worked for me.

I also checked the options in visual studio and the diagnostic tool is enabled during debugging. And i also unchecked the unmanaged code options, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167640/visual-studio-2015-diagnostics-tool-does-not-support-current-debugging-configura) described.

The real strange thing is, that i even not having a "Diagnostics Hub" entry in the output window!??!

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: In my case I had used `$(TargetName)` instead of `$(TargetFileName)` as the startup executable.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue today.
Forgot that I disabled Intellitrace a few months ago.

> Options>IntelliTrace>Enable Intellitrace

Restarted Visual Studio. Voila.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the Environment Variable `TEMP` as following rules and reopen Visual Studio. That works for me. My IDE is Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3.

It must only one path in `TEMP`. For example,

Fail:`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\OTHER_PATH`
 Fail: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\;C:\OTHER_PATH`
 Pass: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`