# The Diagnostics Tools window does not support the current debugging configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

I would like to use diagnostic tool in Visual studio 2015.
When I try to open it, I get this message:
"The Diagnostics Tools window does not support the current debugging configuration"

Same problem was described here:
[Diagnostic tool failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167640/visual-studio-2015-diagnostics-tool-does-not-support-current-debugging-configura)
I have "Use managed Compatibility Mode" unchecked, also "Use Native Compatibility Mode" is unchecked. Even if I change that, the same result.
I have been trying to find the right debugging configuration, but with no success so far. Any idea?
I have VS2015 Enterprise, Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3.

Comment: The same problem with my Visual Studio :(

Comment: Same issue :( I can't profile my ASP.Net core application

Comment: answer for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167640/visual-studio-2015-diagnostics-tool-does-not-support-current-debugging-configura

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here:

1. Uncheck the *Use Managed Compatibility Mode* or *Use Managed Native Mode*. Then **restart** VS.

> Tools –> Options –> Debugging -> General -> (Un-check) 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode'

2. Run VS as admin.