# VS2022 diagnostic tools does not support current debugging configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2022, diagnostic-tools

I have started using VS2022 recently. I'd like to use the diagnostic tool while debugging but the following message appears:

> diagnostic tools does not support current debugging configuration

After some research, I found
[The Diagnostics Tools window does not support the current debugging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785312/the-diagnostics-tools-window-does-not-support-the-current-debugging-configuratio)
and
[Visual Studio 2015 diagnostics tool does not support current debugging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167640/visual-studio-2015-diagnostics-tool-does-not-support-current-debugging-configura)

But they both concern VS2015. Note that in

> Tool>options>debugging>general

the option

> Diagnostic tool while debugging

is enabled (checked)

Does anyone has an idea on a potential solution? I'm using Python so far.

Comment: I think this tool only works for .NET projects, and C++ ones.  It isn't meant for Python.

Comment: That is what I thought, Indeed it works with C++ but not with python. Thanks !