# The Diagnostic Tools window does not support debugging using the 'Script' debug engine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am getting this message in the Diagnostic Tools window in Visual Studio 2015 when debugging a C# MVC web application.

I've checked solutions to a similar problem: [Visual Studio 2015 diagnostics tool does not support current debugging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167640) but using administrator mode and disabling "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" do not help. I've also tried disabling Options -> Debugging -> Just-In-Time -> Script, which still has no effect. It's the only reference I can find to 'Script' and I don't know how to change my debug engine.

I've also tried this solution from the web about setting the Visual Studio locale to the same as the OS, but they're both using US English. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/05/06/known-issue-for-diagnostics-tool-window-in-visual-studio-2015-rc-the-diagnostic-tools-failed-unexpectedly/

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a default MVC web app, and then debug your app, could you use the Diagnostics tool in your side? I test it in my side, it works well using the default settings, my OS and VS all are the English version. So you use the same language version, am I right?

If possible, you could check the following steps:

1. Reset your VS settings:

   Open VS, TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings(I often use the General or C#).
2. Please use the latest VS2015 with update 3.
3. Maybe you could download and install the match VS version as your windows directly, debug it again.

Comment: I get the same error for a new MVC project as well. Resetting the VS settings did not help, and I'm using the latest VS 2015 update 3. I'm kind of just hoping it'll fix itself when we upgrade to 2017 eventually.

Comment: @baochan, I found that other members also got the same issue before using the VS2015 with the US os, does your VS has the en-US (English-United States) language pack installed? Do you mean that you will update your VS to VS2017? If so, how about the result if you use the VS2017?

Comment: VS doesn't show if it's English-US, the only option is "English" (which I tried installing new language packs and this is the only option related to English).  I also tried selecting VS Language "Same as Microsoft Windows" but it still doesn't work. It's weird because it works on other people's machine with (supposedly) the same setup. We're moving to 2017 probably within a few months and I'll check in with the results.

Comment: @baochan, Whether other members also use the same Environment as yours like the Windows and VS language and version. If so, how about copying the DiagnosticsHubMsg.dll file from other machine to yours?

Answer (score 2):

My error message is

> The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly. The Diagnostic Hub output in the Output window may contain additional information.

Try to modify the Environment Variable `TEMP` as following rules and reopen Visual Studio. That works for me, maybe it also works for you. My IDE is Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3.

It must only one path in `TEMP`. For example,

Fail:`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\OTHER_PATH`
 Fail: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\;C:\OTHER_PATH`
 Pass: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: I've upgraded to VS 2017 Professional and it's fixed the problem, so I'm not sure if this was it. I do just have a single path for TEMP now but I'm not sure what it looked like prior to the new install.