# Visual Studio break does not work after return 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Currently i have the problem, that my application does not exit after returning from the main method with `return 0;`. In debug mode, the visual studio debugger is still attached. If i try to go to the point which prevents the application from exeting (Using Debug -> Break All), i get the message:

> Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected bug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).

Is there some thing i don't know with *Break All* in Visual Studio? I've never had this problems before.

Thank you very much!

Comment: this may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580182/visual-studio-2015-rtm-debugging-not-working

Comment: Did you compile a debug of release build? They behave differently by default. Debugging in release afaik is hardly possible with default settings.

Comment: No, just using `Debug` mode when debugging.