# log4net- The application is in break mode

Tags: c#, log4net

I am trying to run my proggram using "log4net", but I get same message "The Application is in break mode".
When I put that line in remarks the programm is running:

```
//private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
//(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Otherwise I get this message: The application is in break mode.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe these will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44270785/982149 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/36204009/982149

Comment: Unrelated: `log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);` This seems not right to me. Where do you have this code? The logger should be a private static readonly **class** variable. It seems you are trying to get a logger locally inside a method?