# Unable to debug C# in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I've recently installed Visual Studio 2017.

I've tested this with a 3 line C# console app. The problem occurs for any solution type with C# - but works for VB.

When I set a breakpoint, it sets correctly, and will break when it reaches it. But will not show the code where it broke and will instead give me the following screen:

[image: The application is in break mode]

My code is very simple:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello there");

            Console.WriteLine("hi");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Putting a break point on any of the `Console.WriteLine`s - and then running the program, will cause the above screen to appear.

I've got the latest version of everything on a fully updated Windows 10.
I found the issue on (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/13290/uwp-breakpoint-doesnt-break-into-source-code-makin.html) which says it has been fixed. It also said

> "Unselect the 2 workloads: "Python development" and "Data science and
>   analytical applications"
>
> After installer finishes, you should be able to debug code"

But I have neither of those options installed.

I have tagged this with C# because the Visual Basic debugger works.

Comment: yay, another kiwi......     why the offtopic vote? this doesn't belong on super user.

Comment: you may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580182/visual-studio-2015-rtm-debugging-not-working

Comment: @KeithNicholas I had already found that one too. None of the solutions  there worked. However, I reinstalled VS, and that fixed the problem