# In VS Installer Project, Commit() is not working properly

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022

Using the Visual Studio Installer Project, I included the initial setup project in **Install** and **Commit** in **Custom Actions** that will perform the downloading of the cabinet file under the `Windows\Temp\Target Folder` folder. Consequently, the zip file will be unzipped.

[image]

I used async/await for the first time in *DownloadCatalog()*, but the zip file wasn't properly downloaded, even though the directory was created. I assumed the installing process stopped the downloading process. I then changed it.

I created the installation file without async. Then I ran it, but the result was the same. This code works fine when running it in an independent project. Do you have any suggestions?

```
namespace IntialSetupApp
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class IntialInstallApp : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        private readonly string temp = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Target Folder\";
        private readonly string zipUrl = @"https://thank.you/so.much";
        private readonly string catalog = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Target Folder\whateverXML.xml";


        public IntialInstallApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
            DownloadCatalog();
        }

        private Task DownloadCatalog()
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = Path.Combine(temp, "ZippedCab.cab");
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(uri, fileName);
                }
                UnzipFile(fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        private Task UnzipFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                CabInfo cab = new CabInfo(filePath);
                cab.Unpack(temp);
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**+Update**
With the above code, I created the console project independently, and it created the folder and completed downloading the file. Therefore,  it seems that **installer** prevents modifying other folders. Is there any workaround way?

Comment: Run your installer with a debug log manybe (or debug it?)To run with log: msiexec <yourmsi> /l*v log.txt. To dbug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279523/debugging-c-sharp-custom-installer-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`, so I updated the code with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel). Then it works fine.